# How to re-enable missing Disclosure arrows?

Tags: finder, macos, settings

OS: Sierra (10.12.6)

I view my folders as List in Finder, but in a recent attempt to refresh my app icon file, I somehow messed up my View settings. From what I've gathered online, I had to set "Arrange by" to "None" (Cmd+Option+0) and "Sort By" to "List" (Cmd+2) if I wanted to return to my previous settings.

However, the usual Disclosure arrow found beside *one* particular folder is now missing and its sub-folders and files are permanently open and displayed instead of collapsed. How do I return the said Disclosure arrow? I'd like to have the ability to control when to expand/collapse it back if possible. This folder was open, by the way, when I was refreshing Finder, if that has any bearing. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried just relaunching Finder? Hold down alt while right clicking on the Finder icon in the dock, then click "Relaunch".

Comment: @Wowfunhappy yup, I did relaunch Finder but through Force Quit/Finder/Relaunch. Thanks for the new shortcut, I'll keep that in mind. Still have the same problem though. EDIT: It worked! Thanks Wow, I don't know why it didn't work before. It just needed another kick, I guess. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Weird little things like this can almost always be resolved by relaunching Finder. There's a number of different ways to do this, but I usually <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>⌥</kbd>-click the Finder icon and select "Relaunch".

When that doesn't work, the next step is to turn the computer off and on again. Basic, I know, but there's a reason they're always mentioned.

Some musings from a former Apple employee on why restarting is effective: https://techreflect.net/2018/04/20/why-does-rebooting-fix-everything/